# Building a data flow with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, dataflow

It has been a few months for me working with SSIS, I'm trying to implement a data flow to replace a sequence of SQL Tasks used to do some data transformation.

Data flow description :

Source :

Each row gives information about energy consumed (X) during a number of days (Y).

Destination :

Energy consumed in Day 1 (X/Y), Day 2 (X/Y) , Day 3 (X/Y), .....

Any ideas about how to implement such logic in a single data flow.

Thanks a lot.

Yacine.

Comment: Can you please post your input and output data?

Comment: Data is too big it's actually kind of hard to put it online.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing correctly, you would like one data flow task that will process the necessary algorithms that are used before storing data - meaning that, **as only an example**, we may have energy amount data and date data, and we'd like to store energy amount data divided by the day number of the year.

One approach to this would be a `Derived Column` between the source and destination, where we could apply mathematical functions to our existing data.  I've done this with weather data before, where an additional column was added which calculated a value to be stored along with the specific day, temperature and forecast based on the latter two.

Another possible approach is an `OLE DB Command`, but note (according to SSIS):

> Runs [a] SQL statement for each row in a data flow. For example, call a
>   'new employee setup' stored procedure for each row in the 'new
>   employees' table. Note: running [a] SQL statement for each row of a
>   large data flow may take a long time.

Comment: Indeed, I have a performance issue with the existing SQL  Statements.

Using a Derived Column can't do it for me since the number of columns to add to the data flow is dynamic (If I have 20 days of consumption I have to get 20 additional rows, if I have 30 days I need 30 additional ones, ....)

Is there a possibility to build new rows via the " Data Flow Scripting Component " ? If there is, I think this would be the only way for me to do what I want.